# Load data from MongoDb to Elasticsearch through python

Tags: python, json, mongodb, elasticsearch

I have some json data loaded in MongoDb. e.g. doc1 = {"id": 1,"name": "x1"},doc2 = {"id": 2,"name": "x2"},doc3 = {"id": 3,"name": "x3"}. Now I want this data to import from MongoDb to Elasticsearch. I wrote this piece of code.

```html
mgclient = MongoClient()
db = mgclient['light-test']
col = db['test']

es1 = Elasticsearch()
print ("Connected", es1.info())

es1.indices.create(index='light-test', ignore=400)

# Pull from mongo and dump into ES using bulk API
actions = []
for data in tqdm(col.find(), total=col.count()):
    data.pop('_id')
    action = {
        "_index": 'light-test',
        "_type": 'test',
        "_source": data
    }
    actions.append(action)
    print("complete")
    
# Dump x number of objects at a time   
    if len(actions) >= 100:
        deque(parallel_bulk(es1, actions), maxlen=0)
        actions = []

print("done")

a = es1.search(index='light-test', body={
  'query': {
    'match_all': {
     }
  }
})
print(a)
```

The problem is in the query returned. The hits shows blank whereas it should had returned the json files.
[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ljSv.png)

Help me in importing the data from MongoDb to Elasticsearch.

Answer (score 3):

```html
app = Flask(__name__)

MONGO_URL = '...'
mgclient = MongoClient(MONGO_URL, ssl=True, ssl_cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_NONE)
db = mgclient['light']
col = db['task']

doc1 = {...}
doc2 = {...}
doc3 = {...}
post_id = col.insert_many([doc1, doc2, doc3])

print(col.count())

es1 = Elasticsearch(...)
ESinfo=(es1.info())

# Pull from mongo and dump into ES using bulk API
actions = []
for data in tqdm(col.find(), total=col.count()):
    data.pop('_id')
    action = {
            "index": {
                    "_index": 'light',
                    "_type": 'task',
                    }
    }
    actions.append(action)
    actions.append(data)

#delete = es1.indices.delete(index = 'light')
request_body = {
    "settings" : {
        "number_of_shards": 1,
        "number_of_replicas": 0
    }
}
es1.indices.create(index='light', body = request_body, ignore=400)
res = es1.bulk(index = 'light', body = actions, refresh = True)

result = col.find()
names = []
for obj in col.find():
    name = obj['name']
    names.append(name)
    print(names)

@app.route('/query')
def Query():
    a = es1.search(index='light', body={
      'query': {
        'match': {
          'name': '...',
         }
      }
    })
    return jsonify(query=a)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
 app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=1024)
```

This has helped. thank you :)